# Triangle using a recursion function

Tags: python, recursion

How do I make a triangle using a recursive function like this:

```
def triangle(3):
```

And the triangle should look like this:

```
    1
  1   1
1   2   1
```

And so on.

Comment: the duplicate computes the value but do not draw as expected

Comment: I am doing an exam and I need some help,can one of you help me?

Comment: The 4th line should be this: 1   3   3   1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
n=4
def triangle(n):
    if n==0:
        return
    num=11**(triangle.n-n)
    print "{}{}".format(" "*n, " ".join(list(str(num))))
    triangle(n-1)
triangle.n = n
triangle(n)
```

Output:

```
    1
   1 1
  1 2 1
 1 3 3 1
```

Comment: That one works but I must do it using recursion.

Comment: My bad, sorry. Thanks!!!